# I have to create a function that takes 2 arguments :a list of string pairs and a string function to boolean values and returns a map

Tags: ocaml

I have to create a function that takes 2 arguments :a list of string pairs and a string function to boolean values and returns a map formed of the first position x from the pair as keys and the values for which the function applied to the second position returns true and i have this kind of error but i think it's the function itself wrong.can you help me please?
         Syntax error: ')' expected, the highlighted '(' might be unmatched

```
 let funct list f=
    List.fold_left(fun acc x->let transform x=
    (if f x then (try (MS.find x acc) with Not_found ->x) in
     MS.add x (transform x) acc else acc) ) MS.empty list;;
```

Comment: Try formatting your code in a sensible manner, then the problem will likely stand out like a sore thumb.

Comment: Why are you using List.fold_left? Why not use List.map?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your question worded, this should work.

```
let mapIt str_p p =
  List.map p str_p
```

You are basically asking to map a list to another list and that is accomplished with List's map.

Note: By map do you mean module Map? Like below?

```
module MyUsers = Map.Make(String)
```